# Is it guaranteed that the function passed to useEffect will be called at least once after the component is called, even in concurrent mode?

Tags: reactjs

Except if exceptions occur of course.

---

I couldn't find a clear answer to this.

In their [reference](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/use-subscription/src/useSubscription.js) useSubscription hook implementation they say:

> It is important not to subscribe while rendering because this can lead to memory leaks.

But it's not clear if it's possible to implement subscriptions in the body that **can't** lead to a memory leaks, or if subscribing in the body **will**, eventually, cause memory leaks if the unsubscription happens inside useEffect.

I'm especially interested in knowing if this holds true under concurrent mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the function passed to useEffect will be called at least once after the component is called, even in concurrent mode?

I think that is **not** guaranteed.

Suppose we start in a situation where your component is not mounted. Rendering begins, and your component is among those that needs to be rendered, so it gets called. But then before it can be committed, a higher priority update comes in, which restarts rendering for a portion of the component tree. In this new render, the parent of your component decides that your component is no longer needed. This render finishes and gets committed, with your component not among the outputs.

It wasn't there before this all started, and it wasn't there after the commit, so its effects do not run. But it did get called during the process, so any side effects in the body of your component happened. You're now subscribed to an event, with no way to unsubscribe from it.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I will have to reimplement my hook differently then. The thing is in their reference implementation there's an extra `checkForUpdates` call precisely because they are subscribing asynchronously, but that could waste a bit of performance juice. I'll figure something out, thanks 

Answer (score 0):

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. **React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.**
>
> The commit phase is usually very fast, but rendering can be slow. For this reason, the upcoming async mode (which is not enabled by default yet) breaks the rendering work into pieces, pausing and resuming the work to avoid blocking the browser. This means that React may invoke render phase lifecycles more than once before committing, **or it may invoke them without committing at all** (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).

Since DOM update happens in the commit phase, and there might be no commit phase at all (in case something happened) I'm guessing that NO, it is not guaranteed that what's in useEffect is called AT ALL.

note: `render` should not contain any side effect, including subscription as these functions might be called more than once leading to an invalid state. Use `useEffect()` for subscribing.

> Render phase lifecycles include the following class component methods:
>
> - constructor componentWillMount (or UNSAFE_componentWillMount)
> - componentWillReceiveProps (or UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps)
> - componentWillUpdate (or UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate)
> - getDerivedStateFromProps shouldComponentUpdate
> - render
> - setState updater functions (the first argument)
>
> Because the above methods might be called more than once, it’s important that they do not contain
> side-effects. Ignoring this rule can lead to a variety of problems,
> including memory leaks and invalid application state. Unfortunately,
> it can be difficult to detect these problems as they can often be
> non-deterministic.